# Finding matching word in MySQL and php

Tags: php, html, mysql, tokenize, matching

Can anyone help me with this problem. I'm trying to echo one thing if something matches and another if something doesn't match.

```
$string = "i love hockey"
$tokenize = strtok($string, " ");

while ($tokenize !== false) {

    echo $tokenize;
```

}

Comment: If there's no match then [mysql_num_rows()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) returns 0. Build your logic around that. Note the nice red warning: the mysql_* functions are deprecated. Please consider a change to mysqli or PDO. Use prepared statements and bind your inputs to parameters. Now you're prone to sql injection.

Answer (score 1):

```
you can use like query


SELECT * FROM `your_table` WHERE `field_name` like '%your_word%'
```

Comment: the query i have works fine, its just if no matches are found i want to tell the user that.

Comment: $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($num_rows == 0) {
echo "No Matches were found";
}
else
{
echo "Matches were found";
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$string = $field['Message'];
$tokenize = strtok($string, " ");
if(!empty($tokenize)) 
{
   $SQL = "SELECT * FROM table 
    WHERE MATCH(item) like '%your word%'";  //only match that word
    $result = mysql_query($SQL);

   if (!empty($result)) 
   {
        while ( $field = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) 
       {

          //here you must print this 
       }
   }
   else
   {
      echo "No Matches were found";
   }
}
```